# Firefox RTCDataChannels not connecting

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, rtcdatachannel

I am trying to create a RTCDataChannel connection between Chrome and Firefox.

I have referenced the sample provided by Mozilla.

http://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/data_test.html

The DataChannel was created before the createOffer method, but it isn't working in Firefox, but works fine in Chrome.

- Chrome (offerer) DataChannel establishment with another Chrome (answerer) browser works.
- Chrome (offerer) DataChannel establishment with Firefox (answerer) does not work.
- Firefox (offerer) DataChannel establishment with another Firefox (answerer) browser does not work.
- Firefox (offerer) DataChannel establishment with Chrome (answerer) works.

Is there any kind of requirements in order for the Firefox DataChannel to work in Firefox?

GetUserMedia is called before creating the DataChannel.

PS: After much checking, I realised that the SDP does not have any m=application port or channel opened. What could be the problem?

Missing lines:

```
m=application 58814 DTLS/SCTP 5000 c=IN IP4 118.189.54.34 a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 16
```

Comment: You may not want to include your IP address in your question....But, not having a line indicating how to connect could indeed be the issue

Comment: Suggest you try again.  Also, since that test you reference is known to work in Firefox (it's a primary testcase for us), if you can't get Firefox to talk to Firefox, something is wrong with your code (which you didn't provide).   You don't need to call GetUserMedia to use a DataChannel.  You should attach the offer and answer (change the IPs if you like for privacy) NOTE: the data_test example/test-code wasn't handling full trickle-only ICE properly back then (we hadn't landed trickle-only at the time).  The test has been updated for Trickle-Only.

Comment: This issue has been resolved. `MozDontOfferDataChannel` flag was added to the createOffer constraints for video stream interoperability between chrome and firefox. It was on Firefox 26-28 where interoperability for video and datachannel is not working with chrome at that time. To close this ticket as upgraded version can interop now.